# Determine whether the sequence converge or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Determine whether the sequence converge or diverges, and if it converges find the limit.
>   $a_n=(4+\sin{n\pi\over2})$

I know that

$$a_n=5,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,\ldots$$

So $a_{2n} = 4,4,4,\ldots \to 4$

$$a_k=3,3,3,\ldots \to 3$$

Or $a_t=5,5,5,\ldots \to 5$

So $a_n$ diverges, but how can I find $k$ or $t$ by $n$ ?

> $b_n =n\sin {1\over n}$

My attempt:

$$t= {1\over n}, t\to 0 \text{ when } n\to \infty.$$

So

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \sin {1\over n} = \lim_{t \to 0}  {\sin t\over t}=1$$

> $$c_n= {{100n}\over{n^{{3}\over{2}}+4}}$$

Let $t=\sqrt{n}$, $t\to \infty$ when $n\to \infty$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  {{100n}\over{n^{{3}\over{2}}+4}}= \lim_{t \to \infty}  {{100t^2}\over{t^{3}+4}}=0$

Is that true ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a$, try:

$$t= 4n+1, k= 4n+3$$

The others look fine.